# PHP (Regex) Check if a string contains at least 4 digits + 2 letters

Tags: php, regex

I would check a string if contains **at least**:

2 letters (a-z) CASE INSENSITIVE
4 digits (0-9)

the order is not important. It could be **a1234b**, **abcd1234**, **4444aa** etc etc.

My actual regex is

```
if (preg_match("/[a-z][^a-z]*[a-z]*[0-9]/i",$string)) {
echo 'secure';
$continue = true;
}
```

and it **doesn't** function if string start with a digit. Thank you

Comment: *"the order is not important"* -- this requirement makes `regex` not the most appropriate tool for the task. Use `regex` to verify if the string contains only letters and digits then count the digits (and/or the letters) and check if there are enough of each kind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^(?=(?:.*[a-zA-Z]){2})(?=(?:.*[0-9]){4})\w+$
```

You can use `lookahead` here to apply the conditions.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vV1wW6/22

```
$re = "/^(?=(?:.*[a-zA-Z]){2})(?=(?:.*[0-9]){4})\\w+$/m"; 
$str = "a1234b\nabcd1234\n4444aa\n12\n12a\n12aa22"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a human-readable check like this:

- Remove all non-letters (`\P{L}` for letters and `\P{M}` for non-diacritics) and if the resulting string length is less than 2, return false
- Remove all non-digits (`\D`) and if the resulting string length is less than 4, return false.

As for

> it doesn't function if string start with a digit

You can add an `if (preg_match('/^\D/', $str))` where `^\D` means *starts with a non-digit*.

PHP code:

```
if (preg_match('/^\D/', $str)) {
    if (mb_strlen(preg_replace('/\D/', '', $str), 'UTF8') < 4 || 
      mb_strlen(preg_replace('/[\P{L}\P{M}]/u', '', $str), 'UTF8') < 2) {
        echo "Invalid";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Valid";
    }
}
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/GchfHx)

Note that to count the length of a Unicode string you need `mb_strlen` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this pattern `(\b[a-zA-Z]+\d{4}[a-z]?|\b[a-zA-Z]+\d{4}|\b\d{4}[a-zA-Z]+)`

See demo here https://regex101.com/r/uJ0vD4/8

**Input**

a1234b, abcd1234, 4444aa, 33333, ab555, aac3566

**Output**

a1234b, abcd1234, 4444aa, aac3566

Answer (score 0):

`^(?=(?:.*[0-9]){4})\w+$` works for this case

for PHP:

```
$re = "/^(?=(?:.*[0-9]){4})\\w+$/m"; 
$str = "a1234b\naaa32233\n"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

for javascript:

```
var re = /^(?=(?:.*[0-9]){4})\w+$/gm; 
var str = 'a1234b\naaa32233\n';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```